# Managing authentication session between Android and Flask-SocketIO

Tags: java, android, python, session, flask-socketio

I am currently building a Flask web application which uses a mixture of HTTP requests (for Basic Authentication and webpages) and Flask-SocketIO (for real time data transfer and requests).  I went with HTTP Basic Authentication to track user login sessions because it is well established and has built in framework for authentication.

For webpages, I pass a username and password through the HTTP authentication header.  It is then read by the server, authenticated against a database, and finally some meta variables with the user ID from the database are set in the Flask Session.  I am using the Flask-Session module to manage a filesystem based session so it can be accessed by both the HTTP requests and Flask-SocketIO.  Here is some relevant code from that process:

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False)
```

Login function

```
def authenticate(username, password):
    uid = users.getUIDByUsername(username) //'users' references the database object
    valid = users.checkUser(uid, password)
    if valid:
        permission = users.getPermissionLevel(uid)
        session["uid"] = uid //'session' references the Flask session
        session["permission"] = permission
    return valid
```

Wrapper annotation for HTTP requests

```
def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def auth_check(*args, **kwargs):
        if users.getAdminCount() == 0:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.adminRegister'))
        if not 'uid' in session or not session['uid']:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return auth_check
```

Wrapper annotation for SocketIO events

```
def permissionSocket(p=users.MEMBER):
    def requires_permission(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def permission_check(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'uid' in session and session['uid']:
                permission = users.getPermissionLevel(session['uid'])
                if permission >= p:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                log.info("Permission denied to user " + str(session['uid']) + " over websockets.")
                return
            log.info("Permission denied to unidentified user.")
            return
        return permission_check
    return requires_permission
```

This all works great for both HTTP requests and SocketIO events when dealing with a web browser.  However, this application also has a sibling for Android.  I need to be able to authenticate sessions with the Android clients as well to maintain security on the Flask server endpoints.  However, I am not sure how to go about HTTP authentication on Android while also maintaining the session for the subsequent SocketIO connection.  The documentation is very sparse regarding Android and Flask-SocketIO as the Google results are overrun by Node.js resources.

So far, I have tried reading the session ID from the 'Set-Cookie' cookie received back from an HTTP authentication request, like so:

```
HTTPURLConnection auth = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(endpoint).openConnection();
auth.setDoOutput(true);
auth.setDoInput(true);
auth.setUseCaches(false);

auth.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
        Base64.encodeToString("admin:beehive".getBytes(), 
        Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP));
auth.connect();
sessionCookie = auth.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
System.out.println("Station Cookie: " + sessionCookie);
```

This had some success; I was able to get what appears to be a valid session ID (c53d8f23-e960-4ff5-acf0-89238206325d).  However, I don't know how to apply this to my SocketIO connection and am still getting permission denied connections.

Here is how I am dealing with the SocketIO connections on Android:

```
//Imports
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

//Connection code
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
opts.query = "session=" + sessionCookie + ";";
Manager manager = new Manager(new URI("http://" + ip), opts);
socket = manager.socket("/socket");
```

What is the best way for me to approach this? Should I create a separate token-type system for the Android clients, or is there a way to get the Android SocketIO client to recognize HTTP/Flask sessions?

**UPDATE**

Disclaimer: There were promising results, but it is still not properly authenticating.

After some digging through source code, I discovered something I missed in the README!  You can register an event listener with the transport that has access to the request header object.  This can be done like so:

```
sessionCookie = decodeCookie(auth.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));
System.out.println("##############################" + sessionCookie);

Manager manager = new Manager(new URI("http://" + url));
socket = manager.socket("/socket");
socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, (Object... transportArgs) -> {
    Transport transport = (Transport) transportArgs[0];

    transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, (Object... headerArgs) -> {
        if (sessionCookie != null) {
            List<String> vars = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sessionCookie.entrySet()) {
                vars.add(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
                if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("session")) {
                    vars.add("io=" + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) headerArgs[0];
            headers.put("Cookie", vars);
        }
    });
});
```

From my source code dive, I only found one place that emitted this event in the EngineIO Java implementation.  When the doOpen method is called for a new Transport object, this event is emitted with an empty header object.  The object, after being loaded by any event handlers, is then passed to the request builder of OkHTTP3 which is the request library in use by this EngineIO implementation.

Here's some of my debug,

Session Cookie Print (Android-Side):

```
{Path=/, session=ade41462-8fd3-4a65-9e23-3c0b540ca8da, Expires=Fri, 28-Sep-2018 05:42:04 GMT, HttpOnly=}
```

I confirmed that the headers were making it back to the Flask-SocketIO server by adding a print of request.headers from within the permissionSocket annotation handler.  The request.headers was equal to this after executing the listener above:

```
Socket Cookie: Cookie: Path=/; session=ade41462-8fd3-4a65-9e23-3c0b540ca8da; io=ade41462-8fd3-4a65-9e23-3c0b540ca8da; Expires=Fri, 28-Sep-2018 05:42:04 GMT; HttpOnly=

User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; SM-G950U Build/R16NW)

Host: 192.168.2.12

Connection: Keep-Alive

Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

So, from that, it seems that this method was a success.  The session ID was successfully persisted through the cookie.  However, I am still getting permission denied from the permissionSocket annotation handler, which means the values of the Flask-Session session object are not being persisted.  I am not very familiar with the inner workings of choosing a cached session object, so I don't really know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

To make the user session accessible to your Android clients all you need to do is make sure the session cookie is sent with the Socket.IO connection request. Sadly, this client does not appear to have the option to send extra headers or cookies (this limitation is referenced in an [issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/520)).

I'm not sure you have a lot of options here. You can modify this client to allow extra headers to be passed, or else you can use a different auth mechanism. The only way this client supports custom arguments is via the query string, so you can pass a token that way.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Do you happen to know of any Java socketio clients that support the session headers?  If not I'll take a look at the protocol and see if I can extend it myself.  Otherwise, a token seems like a fine solution, it's just not ideal since I already have a different system in place.

Comment: Yes, and passing a token in the URL's query string is less secure, as URLs get cached by web servers. I don't know of any other Java client unfortunately. What you need to do is look at how the `query` option is implemented and add a similar one for headers.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question with anything I find that's successful.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added a new UPDATE section to the original question with some of my findings.  Unfortunately, I still don't have it working, but there are some promising results that may spark a solution in you.  I would greatly appreciate any wisdom you can offer.

Comment: @EvanMcCoy based on your code it appears you are sending the `session` cookie back to the server with the cookie name `io`? You need to send it back with the original name of `session`, and then I think the server will be able to restore it and be able to do auth.

Comment: It turns out the final issue was with the credential decoding on the database side in some special case.  I fixed that, and now the login works!  So, at least for my distribution of Flask and Flask-Session, the session ID variable is in fact named "session".  The "io" variable was just me trying things when it wasn't working before.  I'll write an answer with the final findings about the SocketIO Java client soon.